# POST not working with React component

Tags: ajax, node.js, mongodb, post, reactjs

I am following along with a tutorial: http://sahatyalkabov.com/create-a-character-voting-app-using-react-nodejs-mongodb-and-socketio/

I am having problems with POST. When I use Chrome's Postman, I can successfully update the api. But when I try to do it through the react components, I am unable to do so.

This leads me to believe there is a problem with AddCharacter.js, but I can't figure out why. On submit, the handleSubmit function is called, when then will call AddCharacterActions function, and then that will eventually call addCharacter (in AddCharacterActions.js), which is an AJAX POST. So how is this hooked up with what is in server.js (/api/characters)?

server.js

```
...

app.post('/api/characters', function(req, res, next) {

  var gender = req.body.gender;
  var name = req.body.name;

  var character = new Character({

    name: name,
    gender: gender
  });

  character.save(function(err) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.send({ message: name + ' has been added successfully!' });
  });

});
```

AddCharacterActions.js

```
import alt from '../alt';

class AddCharacterActions {
  constructor() {
    this.generateActions(
      'addCharacterSuccess',
      'addCharacterFail',
      'updateName',
      'updateGender',
      'invalidName',
      'invalidGender'
    );
  }

  addCharacter(name, gender) {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/api/characters',
      data: { name: name, gender: gender }
    })
      .done((data) => {
        this.actions.addCharacterSuccess(data.message);
      })
      .fail((jqXhr) => {
        this.actions.addCharacterFail(jqXhr.responseJSON.message);
      });
  }
}

export default alt.createActions(AddCharacterActions);
```

AddCharacter.js

```
import React from 'react';
import AddCharacterStore from '../stores/AddCharacterStore';
import AddCharacterActions from '../actions/AddCharacterActions';

class AddCharacter extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = AddCharacterStore.getState();
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    AddCharacterStore.listen(this.onChange);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    AddCharacterStore.unlisten(this.onChange);
  }

  onChange(state) {
    this.setState(state);
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    console.log("hoasdfa")
    var name = this.state.name.trim();
    var gender = this.state.gender;

    if (!name) {
      AddCharacterActions.invalidName();
      this.refs.nameTextField.getDOMNode().focus();
    }

    if (!gender) {
      AddCharacterActions.invalidGender();
    }

    if (name && gender) {
      AddCharacterActions.addCharacter(name, gender);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='container'>
        <div className='row flipInX animated'>
          <div className='col-sm-8'>
            <div className='panel panel-default'>
              <div className='panel-heading'>Add Character</div>
              <div className='panel-body'>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
                  <div className={'form-group ' + this.state.nameValidationState}>
                    <label className='control-label'>Character Name</label>
                    <input type='text' className='form-control' ref='nameTextField' value={this.state.name}
                           onChange={AddCharacterActions.updateName} autoFocus/>
                    <span className='help-block'>{this.state.helpBlock}</span>
                  </div>
                  <div className={'form-group ' + this.state.genderValidationState}>
                    <div className='radio radio-inline'>
                      <input type='radio' name='gender' id='female' value='Female' checked={this.state.gender === 'Female'}
                             onChange={AddCharacterActions.updateGender}/>
                      <label htmlFor='female'>Female</label>
                    </div>
                    <div className='radio radio-inline'>
                      <input type='radio' name='gender' id='male' value='Male' checked={this.state.gender === 'Male'}
                             onChange={AddCharacterActions.updateGender}/>
                      <label htmlFor='male'>Male</label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <button type='submit' className='btn btn-primary'>Submit</button>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default AddCharacter;
```

AddCharacterStore.js

```
import alt from '../alt';
import AddCharacterActions from '../actions/AddCharacterActions';

class AddCharacterStore {
  constructor() {
    this.bindActions(AddCharacterActions);
    this.name = '';
    this.gender = '';
    this.helpBlock = '';
    this.nameValidationState = '';
    this.genderValidationState = '';
  }

  onAddCharacterSuccess(successMessage) {
    this.nameValidationState = 'has-success';
    this.helpBlock = successMessage;
  }

  onAddCharacterFail(errorMessage) {
    this.nameValidationState = 'has-error';
    this.helpBlock = errorMessage;
  }

  onUpdateName(event) {
    this.name = event.target.value;
    console.log(event.target.value);
    this.nameValidationState = '';
    this.helpBlock = '';
  }

  onUpdateGender(event) {
    this.gender = event.target.value;
    this.genderValidationState = '';
  }

  onInvalidName() {
    this.nameValidationState = 'has-error';
    this.helpBlock = 'Please enter a character name.';
  }

  onInvalidGender() {
    this.genderValidationState = 'has-error';
  }
}

export default alt.createStore(AddCharacterStore);
```

Comment: Do you get an error in your React code?  Do you get a log message showing that your server registered the request?  Do you actually have a request body (check Content-Type perhaps)?  We may need some more info, instead of the code wall here.

Comment: I don't get any errors at all. No log messages. I tried to console.log some text in handleSubmit in AddCharacter.js to see if it would show up, but nothing comes up (which I included in the code above). What is the request body?

Comment: When I type in some text into the field and click on a radio button, I hit enter and the page just refreshes, but nothing shows up in the chrome console.

Comment: Try checking "Preserve log" to get console messages between refreshes.  Sounds like you're somehow missing the preventDefault

Comment: This is what it logs: Navigated to http://localhost:3000/add?gender=Male

Comment: So the page I'm on is localhost:3000/add . But when I submit it goes to localhost:3000/add?gender=Male

Comment: Sounds like you're not preventing the default action somehow.  Start there.